# NStimer I want to call methos in background

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I want to make calls in background for every 3 min, so I am using Twilio for that. I am able to make calls for every 3 in foreground, but when I built app on iPhone device in background it is not working. After some time fb session is getting logout..

```
UIApplication *app1 = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

//create new uiBackgroundTask
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask1 = [app1 beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app1 endBackgroundTask:bgTask1];
    bgTask1 = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

//and create new timer with async call:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   //run function methodRunAfterBackground
    timerForPhone = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[string integerValue] target:self selector:@selector(methodForMakingCall) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerForPhone forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After you put the app into background you don't have much control on it. OS can kill it according to resource needs. Unlike Android, you need to wake your app in order to do some logic. There are some workarounds like using location manager's significant change mechanism but still there is not a designated API for this. You need to keep this in mind whenever you are doing some background logic on iOS.